# Synapse Notebook - Reading CSV file with restricted characters in column names into Parquet files

Tags: pyspark, parquet, azure-synapse

I have a csv file with the column names in the first row. Unfortunately some of the fields have square brackets and spaces in them. Synapse is failing to load with this error:

AnalysisException: Attribute name "xxxxx [xxxxxxxx]" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.

I have looked at [spark-dataframe-column-naming-conventions-restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010507/spark-dataframe-column-naming-conventions-restrictions) which provides some advice on how to restate the column names, but the data is already in a dataframe.

I would appreciate some recommendations on how to approach this issue in pyspark

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same code in the mentioned [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010507/spark-dataframe-column-naming-conventions-restrictions) by [pythonsherpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7547749/pythonsherpa). It will not affect the data in the data frame. This will only replace the column names.

```py
newColumns = []
problematic_chars = ',;{}()='
for column in df.columns:
    column = column.lower()
    column = column.replace(' ', '_')
    for c in problematic_chars:
        column = column.replace(c, '')
    newColumns.append(column)
df = df.toDF(*newColumns)
display(df.limit(10))
```

I tried to replace the invalid characters with this code and sample input csv file in my environment.

**Sample Input:**

[image]
img:1 sample input dataframe

- `col 3` has **space** and `col;4` has **semicolon ;**. The above code will replace them.

**Result**
[image]
img:2 Dataframe with Transformed column names.